# Does Geany provide autocomplete without having to Ctrl-Space everytime?

Tags: ide, geany

Is there a plugin or something to make Geany autocomplete show up as you type (like how Sublime Text does)?. I find it tiring having to press Ctrl+Space everytime I want auto-completion.

Answer (score 1):

The [Autocompletion section of the Geany manual](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#autocompletion) is a little vague on the matter, and a cursory glance suggests that a keypress is required for complete word autocompletion.

Digging a bit deeper in the [Editor Completions preferences section](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#editor-completions-preferences) reveals the *Autocomplete all words in document* option. Testing this option, it seems to get close to what you're looking for. The only drawback is that a word that's not a symbol won't show up in the autocompletion list if there is a symbol that matches. For example, if there's a symbol "engine" and the non-symbol word "engineering" in a document, "engineering" won't be listed for autocompletion until at least "enginee" is typed.